# htaccess leverage browser caching for images

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

I have this code on .htaccess file

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ## 
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
# Media 
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 year"

# Codes
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

# Webfonts
   ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"

   ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

But I am still having the error of "leverage browser caching" when I am trying to test my website speed!

When I tried to view the error details:-

Before using the code above, I had a lot of links!
Now I have only png,jpg,js files.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable mod_expires. 
With apache :

```
a2enmod expires
service apache2 restart
```